# SwiftUI sheet shows sheet with wrong data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list that displays 1, 2, and 3. When the text is tapped the app opens a sheet with the number tapped. However, if I tap the text in the second or third row, the number displayed in the sheet is still 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    @State private var shouldPresentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(self.numbers, id: \.self) { number in
            Text("number: \(number)").sheet(isPresented: self.$shouldPresentSheet) {
                Text("This is sheet number \(number)")
            }.onTapGesture {
                self.shouldPresentSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089069/12299030 - you have same problem.

Comment: @Asperi I completely forgot about extending `Int`, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create *one* sheet instead of *multiple* sheets.

If you want to use `.sheet(isPresented:content:)` you can do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    @State private var selectedNumber: Int?

    var body: some View {
        List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
            Text("number: \(number)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedNumber = number
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: binding) {
            Text("This is a sheet number \(self.selectedNumber ?? 0)")
        }
    }

    var binding: Binding<Bool> {
        .init(
            get: { self.selectedNumber != nil },
            set: { _ in }
        )
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `.sheet(item:content:)`:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3].map(Model.init)
    @State private var selectedNumber: Model?

    var body: some View {
        List(numbers, id: \.id) { number in
            Text("number: \(number.id)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedNumber = number
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedNumber) { item in
            Text("This is a sheet number \(item.id)")
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you decide to use `.sheet(item:content:)` you can add an extension to `Int` (instead of creating a custom struct conforming to `Identifiable`):

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { self }
}
```

as proposed in [Asperi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089069/8697793).