# Swiftui: ForEach button, wrong parameter is passed in a view

Tags: swiftui

I want to open a view each time I click on the corresponding button, the issue is that the view is always called with the same **index** 0 and not the index where the button is created, here is my code:

```
  private var symbols = ["plus.circle", "minus" , "multiply.circle", "divide.circle" ]
 @State private var mathOp = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
 ...
 ForEach((0...symbols.count - 1), id: \.self) { index in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isModal = true
                        }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: symbols[index % symbols.count])
                                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                        }).sheet(isPresented: $isModal , content: {
                            MyView(Op: $mathOp[index %   mathOp.count])
                    })
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Move sheet out of ForEach, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089069/12299030.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is fixed!