# Sheet inside ForEach leads to compiler being unable to type-check this expression Error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to open a sheet when tapping on an item. I followed this questions [Sheet inside ForEach doesn't loop over items SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088893/sheet-inside-foreach-doesnt-loop-over-items-swiftui) answer. I get this Error: `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`, I don't understand what is causing it. I tried multiple solutions and they all lead to the same Error.

```
@State var selectedSong: Int? = nil
@State var songList: [AlbumSong] = []

VStack {
ForEach(songList.enumerated().reversed(), id: \.offset) { index, song in
  HStack {
    Text("\(index + 1).").padding(.leading, 8)
      VStack {
                      Text(song.title)
                      Text(song.artist)
             }
           }.onTapGesture {
              self.selectedSong = index
           }
         }
       }
}
.sheet(item: self.$selectedSong) { selectedMovie in
       SongPickerEdit(songList: $songList, songIndex: selectedMovie)
```

I also tried setting `songIndex` to being an `AlbumSong` and then implemented this sheet:

```
.sheet(item: self.$selectedSong) { 
SongPickerEdit(songList: $songList, songIndex: self.songList[$0])
}
```

```
struct SongPickerEdit: View { 
    @Binding var songList: [AlbumSong]
    @State var songIndex: Int?
var body: some View {
  }
}

struct AlbumSong: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let title: String
    let duration: TimeInterval
    var image: String
    let artist: String
    let track: String
}
```

Comment: You don’t need the `if` condition, if the array is empty the `ForEach` loop will not be entered anyway.

Comment: Did you try to build the project again? Sometimes, the preview didn't throw the correct error

Comment: Yes, I also restarted Xcode many times and cleaned the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making `selectedSong` an `AlbumSong?`? The `item:` parameter needs to be an `Identifiable` binding, but `Int` is not `Identifiable`.

```
@State var selectedSong: AlbumSong? = nil
@State var songList: [AlbumSong] = []

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(songList.enumerated().reversed(), id: \.offset) { index, song in
            HStack {
                Text("\(index + 1).").padding(.leading, 8)
                VStack {
                      Text(song.title)
                      Text(song.artist)
                }
            }.onTapGesture {
                self.selectedSong = song
            }
        }
    }.sheet(item: $selectedSong) { song in
        SongPickerEdit(songList: $songList, song: song)
    }
}
```

Note that `SongPickerEdit` would look like this:

```
struct SongPickerEdit: View {
    @State var song: AlbumSong
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(song.title), \(song.artist)")
    }
}
```

If you really need the index for some reason, you can add the song list binding back in and use `songList.index { $0.id == song.id }` to find the index if the list is not too long.

Otherwise, you can make your own `Identifiable` type `SongAndIndex` that uses the same `id` as `AlbumSong`, but with an extra index property, and use that as the type of `selectedSong`.

A third way would be to use the `sheet(isPresented:)` overload, but this way you end up with 2 sources of truth:

```
@State var selectedSongIndex: Int? = nil {
    didSet {
        if selectedSongIndex != nil {
            isSheetPresented = true
        }
    }
}
@State var isSheetPresented: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if !isSheetPresented {
            selectedSongIndex = nil
        }
    }
}

...

}.sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
    SongPickerEdit(songList: $songList, songIndex: selectedSongIndex)
}
```

`selectedSongIndex` also won't be set to nil when the user dismisses the sheet.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you did differently but this somehow works for me. I also tried making the selectedSong an AlbumSong but I guess my sheet looked different

Comment: What is the reason I cannot use an Int? I want to change the values of the selected song and therefore I need the index

Comment: @AdamLeet As I added in the edit, this is because `Int` is not `Identifiable`. You can also try using the `sheet(isPresented:)` overload instead.